# Pull Outlook Email's content into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pywin32

I am trying to pull email's content into pandas dataframe, the email content has a table copied from excel. However, when I am trying to use `pd.read_html`, python shows :`no tables were found`. Here is my code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).folders("Target Folder")
items = folder.items
items.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", Descending=True)
target_msg = items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'XXX'")
for i in list(target_msg)[:1]:
     df = pd.read_html(i.Body)

ValueError: No tables found
```

Is it anyway to parse the content of the email into dataframe or at least save it into csv or txt file?

Comment: If it's copied as a bitmap, then there's probably no (easy) way to load it into a dataframe. It would probably be easier to ask the person who sent the email to include the spreadsheet as an attachment instead.

Comment: But i am able to read message.Body as a string

Comment: Is the table data in that string?

Comment: yes, the table data is in that string.

Comment: Can you share the contents of that string?

Comment: yes, it looks like this: "first line: some text , next line: table name, 3 rd line: actual table"